# Open sets having an empty intersection but the intersection of their closure is not empty

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $V_{n}$ is a decreasing sequence of (bounded) open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ with $m\geq1$. Suppose  the intersection of all $V_{n}$ is empty, and let $F$ be the intersection of the closures of $V_{n}$. Can we say that there exists $N$ such that every $x$ in $F$ belongs to the boundary of $V_{n}$, for $n\geq N$?

(This question is suggested by setting $V_{n}=(0,1/n)$)

Comment: I think when $\bigcap_n V_n =\emptyset$ that $\bigcap_n \overline{V_n}$ will always have empty interior, so the supposition is superfluous.

Comment: You are right. I fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $V_n$ be the union of a small open interval around $1/m$ for each $m>n$ and a small open interval with left endpoint $1/m$ for each $m\leq n$, the intervals being small enough to not overlap and shrinking to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.  Then $F=\{0\}\cup\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}$ but $1/m$ is only in the boundary of $V_n$ if $n\geq m$.

Comment: As the intervals do not overlap, they are not nested as required.

Comment: $V_n$ is not a single interval, it is a union of intervals, one for each $m$.

Comment: The verbal description fails.